# How to efficiently highlight a region given a START and END position expressed as line_nr, col_nr?

Tags: highlight

Say that I want to highlight a region expressed in terms of two coordinates of the form `(line, column)`, e.g. `C1 =  (l1, c1)` to `C2 = (l2, c2)`.

I read `:h matchaddpos()` but it seems that you can only specify entire lines or single characters to highlight, or you can express a range through starting position + length, which would lead to not very readable solutions, although the latest could be interesting as it would require the definition of a distance in the metric space built on the buffer’s coordinates set.

`:h matchadd()` requires a pattern but I am not sure how should I specify patterns for ranges expressed in terms of coordinates of the form `(line, column)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match from line 2 column 3 to line 4 column 5 (not included) you could use the following regular expression:

```
\%2l\%3c\_.*\%4l\%5c
```

- `\%2l` match only on line 2
- `\%3c` match only right before character 3
- `\_.*` match any list of characters including new line

More information with:

- `:h /\%c`
- `:h /\%l`

You could then:

```
:call matchadd(group, '\%2l\%3c\_.*\%4l\%5c')
```

Where `group` is an highlighting group.

E.g:

```
:call matchadd("ErrorMsg", '\%2l\%3c\_.*\%4l\%5c')
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll take the regex as-is and I can understand what does it mean, but from a pedagogical standpoint it would be nice if you complete your answer by breaking down the regex explaining what each part does (possibly with reference to the :h pages) pages and finally  showing how to apply it in the context of matchadd().  ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update the answer :-)

Comment: Top! One small note: `ErrorMsg` should be quoted. ;-)

Comment: Thanks I couldn't test in front of the barbecue ;-)

Comment: Ahahahah good one! I hope you enjoyed your bbq and had a great one! :D Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use text properties, with the added benefit of not having to do as much bookkeeping to keep the highlight in place:

```
call prop_type_add('number', {'highlight': 'Constant'})
call prop_add(11, 12, #{type: 'number', end_lnum: 12, end_col: 13})
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a solution that, if on the one hand seems efficient due to the utilization of `matchaddpos()` instead of `matchadd()`, on the other hand it contains a number of `for` loops:

```
def BuildMatchPattern(l0: number, c0: number, l1: number, c1: number): list<any>
    # Say that we yanked from line 23, col 15 to line 26, col 19.
    # This function return the following list [[23, 15], 24, 25, [26, 19]]
    var match_pattern = []
    # Yank on one line
    if l0 == l1
        for c in range(c0, c1)
            add(match_pattern, [l0, c])
        endfor
    else
        # Yank on two consecutive lines
        # First line
        for c in range(c0, col('$'))
            add(match_pattern, [l0, c])
        endfor
        # Second line
        for c in range(1, c1)
            add(match_pattern, [l1, c])
        endfor
    endif

    # Yanked more than two lines (you must get the whole intermediate lines)
    if l1 - l0 >= 2
        for l in range(l0 + 1, l1 - 1)
            add(match_pattern, l)
        endfor
    endif
    return match_pattern
enddef

    matchaddpos('Visual', BuildMatchPattern(l0, c0, l1, c1))
```